# Discrete time Markov chain

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

The successive results of chess player against a chess program follow
a Markov chain on the states 0 for win  1 for loss and 2 for neither with the
corresponding matrix`
$
P=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
   \frac{3}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4}\\   0 &  \frac{3}{4} & \frac{1}{4} \\ \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4}      \end{array} } \right]
$

- Find the n step matrix
- Find the average of the long-term wins of this player
- The expected number of a victory to the next victory

solution

After some work I found the n step matrix which is

$
P^n=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
   \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}(\frac{3}{4})^n & \frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{3}(
\frac{3}{4})^n & \frac{1}{4}\\  \frac{1}{2}-\frac{2}{3}(\frac{3}{4})^n &  \frac{1}{4}+\frac{2}{3}(
\frac{3}{4})^n & \frac{1}{4} \\ \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4}      \end{array} } \right]
$

My problem is more understanding what the question is asking for ??!!

Asking for "the average of the long-term wins of this player" does it mean taking the limit of $P^n$ as n goes to $+\infty$? then taking the entry $P^{n}_{00}$ which is $\frac{1}{2}$ as n goes to $+\infty$.. is this correct?
For the last one I have no idea ...

Comment: There is a theorem behind these questions you are asked to solve, which uses the limit of the nth power of P. Any idea about what this result might be?

Comment: No..can you tell?

Comment: How come you were led to solve this then? Where do they ask people to hammer a nail without giving them a hammer?

Comment: I gave an answer for the second one .. I need a confirmation.

Comment: And an explanation of the third one .. because it is not clear for me.

Comment: Any hint or which theorem you are talking about?

Comment: Sound like part 2 is asking for the stationary distribution.

Comment: Still no explanation about the circumstances that make you attack such problems without the needed background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked for some confirmation. The solution of $\mathrm\sigma P = \sigma$ gives 
$\sigma = (1/2, 1/4, 1/4),$ which you can verify by multiplication.
Because this is an ergodic Markov Chain, the stationary distribution $\sigma$
is also the long run (limiting) distribution.

My interpretation of the 'average long-term wins' would be that over the
long term the player wins 1/2 of the time and loses 1/4 of the time. Thus, over the long run,
the expected net number of wins would be 1/4 of the number of games played.

I have no idea the level of your course or what you have covered. So I don't
know what method you are expected to use to get a general form for $P^n.$ (Perhaps by induction for this particular problem; perhaps some general method.)

I am showing you computations from R statistical software for $P^2$ and $P^4,$ and you can compare the
results with your formula. (R is free from `r-project.org`. Maybe you have
access to MatLab, which ought to do much the same computations.)

```
> P = .25*matrix(c(3,0,1,
+                  0,3,1,
+                  2,1,1), nrow=3, byrow=T)
> P
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 0.75 0.00 0.25
[2,] 0.00 0.75 0.25
[3,] 0.50 0.25 0.25
> P2 = P %*% P;  P2       # %*% is for matrix multiplication
       [,1]   [,2] [,3]
[1,] 0.6875 0.0625 0.25
[2,] 0.1250 0.6250 0.25
[3,] 0.5000 0.2500 0.25
> P4 = P2 %*% P2;  P4
          [,1]      [,2] [,3]
[1,] 0.6054688 0.1445312 0.25
[2,] 0.2890625 0.4609375 0.25
[3,] 0.5000000 0.2500000 0.25
```

A general method for getting the stationary distribution is to use
eigenvectors. If you are not familiar with a matrix-algebra approach,
then you can skip this part  and just check that $\sigma$ (`s` in the code) is the
correct stationary vector. (R computes right eigenvectors, hence the transpose `t(p)`.
The eigenvector you want is from the first column `[,1]`of the output matrix of eigenvectors, but it has to be
normed so its elements sum to unity. Eigenvectors may have complex
entries, but not in the one you need. Using `as.numeric`cleans up the output by getting rid of
irrelevant complex number notation.)

```
> g = as.numeric(eigen(t(P))$vector[,1])
> s = g/sum(g)
> s
[1] 0.50 0.25 0.25

> s%*%P
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  0.5 0.25 0.25
```

If 'victories' happen half of the time over the long run, then the expected
wait from one victory to the next should be $1/.5 = 2.$ (Similar to the mean waiting time
for a geometric distribution.)

My guess is you might be trying to take a shortcut by skipping to the
problems without first digesting the chapter and lectures. Maybe not the
best strategy. Maybe some of this
will help you understand the background material in order to make
sense of all parts of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

One more approach to confirmation—draw the state diagram (omitting, below, the self-loops, for clarity):

[image]

Based on probability flux balances, we can write

$$
\frac{1}{4} p_\text{win} = \frac{1}{2} p_\text{draw}
$$

and

$$
\frac{1}{4} p_\text{draw} = \frac{1}{4} p_\text{lose}
$$

which (along with the probabilities summing to one) yields

$$
p_\text{win} = \frac{1}{2}
$$
$$
p_\text{draw} = p_\text{lose} = \frac{1}{4}
$$

One does need the same arguments about ergodicity adduced by BruceET in his answer.

Comment: Nice explanation for this simple chain (+1). Certainly more generally accessible than the eigenvector method. (I teach a course in which we simulate Markov chains; since students are already using a computer for that, matrix methods are convenient for chains with finite state spaces.)